# Rally authentication failure while using with rally_api gem

Tags: ruby, rally

I am trying to connect to rally using rally_api gem but it gives me error like,
**Error 401 The username or password you entered is incorrect.**

but when i tries to login directly through website it logs in me.

@config = {}
    @config[:base_url]  = "https://trial.rallydev.com/slm"    # This is the default setting.
    @config[:username]  = "my_username"
    @config[:password]  = "my_pass"
    @config[:workspace] = "workspace name"
    @config[:project]   = "project name"

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to connect to trial or production (trail.rallydev.com or rally1.rallydev.com) ?

A code making connection to Rally shown [here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby).

```
#Setting custom headers
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "My Utility"
headers.vendor = "MyCompany"
headers.version = "1.0"

#or one line custom header
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new({:vendor => "Vendor", :name => "Custom Name", :version => "1.0"})

config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username]   = "user@company.com"
config[:password]   = "password"
config[:workspace]  = "Workspace Name"
config[:project]    = "Project Name"
config[:headers]    = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
```

Do you have non-alpha numeric characters in the password? (Exclamation point certainly works,but there can be characters that problematic).
Also , to set the WS API version use:

```
config[:version] = "v2.0"
```